# How can I concatenate user input in a list

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I would like to get codes from the user and insert it in a list, but the problem is when the user say that don't wanna insert more codes. I don't saved a list with the numbers because I'm using recursion to call the method again, so when I should return the list I don't have it.

```
insertCode :: [Integer]
insertCode = do
    putStrLn "Code:"
    code <- getLine
    putStrLn "Another? (Y/N)"
    if(resp == "Y" || resp == "y") then (read code::String->Integer):insertCode else --I don't know
```

I'm sorry for my stupids questions, I imagine that is obvious but I have a problem with functional programming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your type signature is wrong. `insertCode` uses the `IO` monad, so the type must be `IO [Integer]`. You are also missing the conversion of `code` from a `String` to an `Integer` (I use `readLn` to accomplish that; you were trying to convert `code` into a *function*, not an `Integer`) and you are missing a `getLine` to get the Y/N response from the user.

Once that is fixed, you might write something like the following:

```
insertCode :: IO [Integer]
insertCode = do
    putStrLn "Code:"
    code <- readLn
    putStrLn "Another? (Y/N)"
    response <- getLine
    result <- if (response == "Y" || response == "y")
              then insertCode
              else return []
    return (code : result)
```

This is a little verbose, but tries to be explicit about how the monad is used. Whether the user enters Y or N, `code` must be appended to a list extracted from a monad: either a list extracted from a recursive use of `insertCode`, or an explicit empty list.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I have a little problem...I was receiving the message "Not in scope: `result`'", so I put the last line inside `else do` but now appears this message "The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      result <- main
"

Comment: Yeah, right after I hit "submit" I realized there was at least one problem, so I took a moment to actually run the code to fix it up.

Comment: I have a doubt, exists any way to convert the `IO [Integer]` to `Integer`

Comment: There is a way, but you almost certainly don't want to use it. Take `length` as an example. Instead of extracting the list from the `IO` value to pass to `length`, use `fmap` to create a function that works in the `IO` monad. `fmap length :: IO [Integer] -> IO Int`.

Comment: @Marcio Converting `IO  [Integer]` to `[Integer]` means to convert a program which can ask the user for a list of integers, into a program which does not ask the user producing the same list. It is impossible without completely breaking the type system. The good news is that that conversion is practically never needed, thanks to the functor/applicative/monad stuff. Use `fmap` or use `do ... ; x <- myIOInt ; ....` to run the IO action and get the integer list.